# How to I compare two dictionary value lists, and update list value if another list value has changed in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries with list values; an old, and new version.

Old List:

```
old dict = {'bob': ['green', '5'],
 'jeff': ['blue', '4'],
 'sally': ['white', '7']}
```

New List:

```
new_dict = {'bob': ['green', '5'],
 'jeff': ['blue', '4'],
 'sally': ['black', '7']}
```

If the first list value changes (in this case, the colour on the new list), I would like to update the 2nd value of the list (the number, to let's say 0).

What is the best solution in Python3 to compare the first dictionary values between two dictionary value lists, and update the second dictionary list value if the first list value has been updated?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution that you felt wasn’t best?

Comment: Not yet, currently messing with some ideas in iPython, but wouldn't mind being lead in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the old_dict checking its values against the new_dict and change them if they don't agree.

```
for k,v in old_dict.items():
    if k in new_dict and v[0] != new_dict[k][0]:
        new_dict[k][1] = '0';
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I had a brain fart when it came to line 2/3. I have tested this logic out, and gave me the results I needed.